# What's wrong with my delete button on my HTML/Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple calculator using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm done with the calculation part and the design but I'm having a hard time with my DEL button. My DEL button is supposed to backspace the last key pressed on the calculator.

I made a function called del() on my .js and this is what it looks like so far:

```
function del()
    {
    document.getElementById("dis").value = (document.getElementById("dis").value.getLength) - 1;
    }
```

"dis" is the id of my calculator's display.

Comment: For future questions: your question will be received better if you mention more clearly what you want to happen, what happens instead, and what you've done/researched to try to fix it.  If you don't have answers to those, it'll probably be good for you to get some anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
var val = document.getElementById("dis").value;
if(val.length > 0){
val = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
document.getElementById("dis").value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is setting the display's value to:

```
(document.getElementById("dis").value.getLength) - 1
```

Which is the number of digits (string length) of the displayed value minus one, so if the value was "500", it would set it to 2 (3-1).  Clearly not what you want.

What you want is to get the value, cut it down to just the characters you want (probably with [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)) and then re-set the value to that string.

Answer (score 0):

`.getlength` is undefined. If you want the length of the string, you should use `str.length`. Anyway, if you want to remove the last character, use this

```
str=str.substr(0,-1);
```

or, for your code

```
document.getElementById("dis").value = document.getElementById("dis").substr(0,-1);
```

Comment: `length()` is not a function either, it's an attribute. And it doesn't do the same thing as substr().

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, un-downvoted.  I was perplexed.  Still, a bit more explanation on what they were and weren't doing would be helpful, since they clearly are not familiar with things.  Just handing code they can copy/paste doesn't help them in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use String operations...[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

something like this should work:

```
document.getElementById("dis").value = document.getElementById("dis").value.slice(0, -1)
```